# Cygwin Package Manager - Installed Packages Not Appearing

Tags: windows-8.1, cygwin

I'm trying to install a package for Cygwin. When installing, Cygwin reports no errors yet when I go to the Cygwin terminal I find the packages are not installed.

An example with `wget`.

- I call Cygwin setup executable with the `-M` flag via command prompt.
- I choose the `wget` package.
  [image]
- Install the extra required packages

Cygwin reports no errors. Only thing to note is that it cannot find `McShield`.

Doing a `which wget` returns that it cannot find `wget`.

The `setup.log` shows these two erros:

```
2015/06/09 14:59:16 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/installed.db) failed 2 No such file or directory
2015/06/09 14:59:17 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/timestamp) failed 2 No such file or directory
```

Actually looking in `/etc/setup/` shows that both exist.

---

**Extra Info**

- This is on Windows 8.1
- I'm doing this all as administrator
- I've tried using `cmd` and `powershell`
- I'm using the latest version of Cygwin (2.781 from the [install page](https://cygwin.com/install.html))

---

**Full `setup.log`**

```
2015/06/09 14:58:34 Starting cygwin install, version 2.871
2015/06/09 14:58:34 User has backup/restore rights
2015/06/09 14:58:34 Current Directory: C:\Users\Ryan\Downloads
2015/06/09 14:58:34 Could not open service McShield for query, start and stop. McAfee may not be installed, or we don't have access.
2015/06/09 14:58:37 source: network install
2015/06/09 14:58:43 root: E:\cygwin64 system
2015/06/09 14:58:59 Selected local directory: E:\Downloads
2015/06/09 14:59:00 net: Direct
2015/06/09 14:59:02 site: http://mirrors.163.com/cygwin/
2015/06/09 14:59:16 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/installed.db) failed 2 No such file or directory
2015/06/09 14:59:17 io_stream_cygfile: fopen(/etc/setup/timestamp) failed 2 No such file or directory
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency bzip2: Selecting version 1.0.6-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency ca-certificates: Selecting version 2.4-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency groff: Selecting version 1.22.3-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency less: Selecting version 471-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libargp: Selecting version 20110921-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libattr1: Selecting version 2.4.46-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libblkid1: Selecting version 2.25.2-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libbz2_1: Selecting version 1.0.6-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libcrypt0: Selecting version 1.1-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libdb5.3: Selecting version 5.3.21-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libffi6: Selecting version 3.2.1-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libgcc1: Selecting version 4.9.2-3 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libgdbm4: Selecting version 1.11-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libgmp10: Selecting version 6.0.0a-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libiconv: Selecting version 1.14-3 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libiconv2: Selecting version 1.14-3 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libintl8: Selecting version 0.19.4-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency liblzma5: Selecting version 5.2.1-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libmpfr4: Selecting version 3.1.2-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libncursesw10: Selecting version 5.9-20150516-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libp11-kit0: Selecting version 0.22.1-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libpcre1: Selecting version 8.37-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libpipeline1: Selecting version 1.4.0-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libpopt0: Selecting version 1.16-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libsmartcols1: Selecting version 2.25.2-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libssp0: Selecting version 4.9.2-3 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libstdc++6: Selecting version 4.9.2-3 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libtasn1_6: Selecting version 4.4-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency libuuid1: Selecting version 2.25.2-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency lynx: Selecting version 2.8.7-2 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency p11-kit: Selecting version 0.22.1-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency p11-kit-trust: Selecting version 0.22.1-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency popt: Selecting version 1.16-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency xz: Selecting version 5.2.1-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency zlib0: Selecting version 1.2.8-3 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:54 Adding required dependency _update-info-dir: Selecting version 00433-1 for installation.
2015/06/09 15:01:56 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/_autorebase/_autorebase-001002-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:01:59 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/_update-info-dir/_update-info-dir-00433-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:02:02 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/alternatives/alternatives-1.3.30c-10.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:02:11 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/base-cygwin/base-cygwin-3.8-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:02:19 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/base-files/base-files-4.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:03:23 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.3.39-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:03:26 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:03:37 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ca-certificates/ca-certificates-2.4-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:03:57 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/coreutils/coreutils-8.23-4.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:04:10 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/cygutils/cygutils-1.4.14-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:06:11 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/cygwin/cygwin-2.0.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:06:14 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/dash/dash-0.5.8-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:06:17 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/editrights/editrights-1.03-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:06:23 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/file/file-5.22-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:06:35 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/findutils/findutils-4.5.12-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:06:56 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gawk/gawk-4.1.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:07:00 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/getent/getent-2.18.90-4.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:08:02 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/grep/grep-2.21-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:08:39 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/groff/groff-1.22.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:08:44 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gzip/gzip-1.6-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:08:48 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/hostname/hostname-3.13-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:08:57 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/texinfo/info/info-5.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:09:00 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ipc-utils/ipc-utils-1.0-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:09:08 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/less/less-471-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:09:12 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libargp/libargp-20110921-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:09:14 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/attr/libattr1/libattr1-2.4.46-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:09:18 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/libblkid1/libblkid1-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:09:22 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/bzip2/libbz2_1/libbz2_1-1.0.6-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:09:26 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/crypt/libcrypt0/libcrypt0-1.1-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:10:35 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/db/libdb5.3/libdb5.3-5.3.21-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:10:40 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libffi/libffi6/libffi6-3.2.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:10:44 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gcc/libgcc1/libgcc1-4.9.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:10:46 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gdbm/libgdbm4/libgdbm4-1.11-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:10:54 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gmp/libgmp10/libgmp10-6.0.0a-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:10:58 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libiconv/libiconv-1.14-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:11:11 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libiconv/libiconv2/libiconv2-1.14-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:11:12 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gettext/libintl8/libintl8-0.19.4-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:11:16 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/xz/liblzma5/liblzma5-5.2.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:11:21 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/mpfr/libmpfr4/libmpfr4-3.1.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:11:28 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ncurses/libncursesw10/libncursesw10-5.9-20150516-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:11:52 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/openssl/libopenssl100/libopenssl100-1.0.2a-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:02 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/p11-kit/libp11-kit0/libp11-kit0-0.22.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:17 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/pcre/libpcre1/libpcre1-8.37-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:20 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libpipeline/libpipeline1/libpipeline1-1.4.0-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:22 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/popt/libpopt0/libpopt0-1.16-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:34 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/readline/libreadline7/libreadline7-6.3.8-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:39 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/libsmartcols1/libsmartcols1-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:43 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gcc/libssp0/libssp0-4.9.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:52 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gcc/libstdc++6/libstdc++6-4.9.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:54 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libtasn1/libtasn1_6/libtasn1_6-4.4-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:56 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/libuuid1/libuuid1-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:12:58 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/login/login-1.11-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:13:18 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/lynx/lynx-2.8.7-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:13:26 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/man-db/man-db-2.7.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:13:29 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/mintty/mintty-1.2-beta1-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:13:47 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/openssl/openssl-1.0.2a-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:13:51 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/p11-kit/p11-kit-0.22.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:13:54 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/p11-kit/p11-kit-trust/p11-kit-trust-0.22.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:15:28 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:15:29 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_autorebase/perl_autorebase-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:15:50 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_base/perl_base-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:16:42 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_manpages/perl_manpages-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:17:53 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_pods/perl_pods-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:18:00 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/popt/popt-1.16-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:18:10 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/rebase/rebase-4.4.1-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:18:12 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/run/run-1.3.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:18:19 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/sed/sed-4.2.2-3.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:18:30 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/tar/tar-1.28-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:18:33 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ncurses/terminfo/terminfo-5.9-20150516-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:18:40 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/tzcode/tzcode-2014j-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:18:50 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/util-linux-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:18:58 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/vim/vim-minimal/vim-minimal-7.4.729-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:00 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/which/which-2.20-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:04 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/xz/xz-5.2.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:12 Downloaded E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/zlib/zlib0/zlib0-1.2.8-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:13 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/_autorebase/_autorebase-001002-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:13 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/_update-info-dir/_update-info-dir-00433-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:13 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/alternatives/alternatives-1.3.30c-10.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:14 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/base-cygwin/base-cygwin-3.8-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:14 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/base-files/base-files-4.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:14 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/bash/bash-4.3.39-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:15 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/bzip2/bzip2-1.0.6-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:15 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ca-certificates/ca-certificates-2.4-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:15 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/coreutils/coreutils-8.23-4.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:17 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/cygutils/cygutils-1.4.14-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:17 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/cygwin/cygwin-2.0.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:17 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/dash/dash-0.5.8-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:18 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/editrights/editrights-1.03-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:18 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/file/file-5.22-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:18 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/findutils/findutils-4.5.12-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:18 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gawk/gawk-4.1.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:18 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/getent/getent-2.18.90-4.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:18 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/grep/grep-2.21-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:19 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/groff/groff-1.22.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gzip/gzip-1.6-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/hostname/hostname-3.13-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/texinfo/info/info-5.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ipc-utils/ipc-utils-1.0-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/less/less-471-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libargp/libargp-20110921-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/attr/libattr1/libattr1-2.4.46-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/libblkid1/libblkid1-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/bzip2/libbz2_1/libbz2_1-1.0.6-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/crypt/libcrypt0/libcrypt0-1.1-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/db/libdb5.3/libdb5.3-5.3.21-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libffi/libffi6/libffi6-3.2.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gcc/libgcc1/libgcc1-4.9.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gdbm/libgdbm4/libgdbm4-1.11-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gmp/libgmp10/libgmp10-6.0.0a-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:22 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libiconv/libiconv-1.14-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libiconv/libiconv2/libiconv2-1.14-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gettext/libintl8/libintl8-0.19.4-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/xz/liblzma5/liblzma5-5.2.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/mpfr/libmpfr4/libmpfr4-3.1.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ncurses/libncursesw10/libncursesw10-5.9-20150516-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/openssl/libopenssl100/libopenssl100-1.0.2a-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/p11-kit/libp11-kit0/libp11-kit0-0.22.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/pcre/libpcre1/libpcre1-8.37-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libpipeline/libpipeline1/libpipeline1-1.4.0-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/readline/libreadline7/libreadline7-6.3.8-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/libsmartcols1/libsmartcols1-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gcc/libssp0/libssp0-4.9.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/gcc/libstdc++6/libstdc++6-4.9.2-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/libtasn1/libtasn1_6/libtasn1_6-4.4-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/libuuid1/libuuid1-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/login/login-1.11-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:23 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/lynx/lynx-2.8.7-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:24 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/man-db/man-db-2.7.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:25 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/mintty/mintty-1.2-beta1-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:25 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/openssl/openssl-1.0.2a-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:25 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/p11-kit/p11-kit-0.22.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:25 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/p11-kit/p11-kit-trust/p11-kit-trust-0.22.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:25 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:32 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_autorebase/perl_autorebase-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:32 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_base/perl_base-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:32 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_manpages/perl_manpages-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:35 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/perl/perl_pods/perl_pods-5.14.4-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:36 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/popt/popt-1.16-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:37 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/rebase/rebase-4.4.1-1.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:37 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/run/run-1.3.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:37 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/sed/sed-4.2.2-3.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:37 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/tar/tar-1.28-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:37 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/ncurses/terminfo/terminfo-5.9-20150516-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:38 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/tzcode/tzcode-2014j-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:41 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/util-linux/util-linux-2.25.2-2.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:41 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/vim/vim-minimal/vim-minimal-7.4.729-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:41 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/which/which-2.20-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/09 15:19:41 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/xz/xz-5.2.1-1.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:42 Extracting from file://E:\Downloads/http%3a%2f%2fmirrors.163.com%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/zlib/zlib0/zlib0-1.2.8-3.tar.xz
2015/06/09 15:19:42 Changing gid back to original
2015/06/09 15:19:42 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\dash.exe "/etc/postinstall/0p_000_autorebase.dash"
2015/06/09 15:19:45 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/000-cygwin-post-install.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:45 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/update-info-dir.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:46 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/coreutils.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:46 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/bash.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:46 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/base-files-mketc.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:46 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/base-files-profile.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:47 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/ca-certificates.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:48 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/lynx.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:48 running: E:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/man-db.sh"
2015/06/09 15:19:48 Changing gid to Administrators
2015/06/09 15:19:57 note: Installation Complete
2015/06/09 15:19:57 Ending cygwin install
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that I originally installed it on my `C:\` drive and then moved it onto another drive.

I tested it by installing it to `C:\` and then doing `setup -M` and installing `wget`. This worked.

I then moved my `Cygwin` folder to my `E:\` drive and did `setup -M` to install curl. Doing a `which curl` returns that it could not be found.

I realise the problem is that `Cygwin` still though the installation was in the `C:\` drive i.e the `Root Directory` was set to `C:\cygwin64`. I fixed this by running the `setup.exe` and changing the `Root Directory` to point to the correct location.

Now I can `setup.exe -M` to install packages.

Comment: I'm happy you managed to resolve it ;)

Answer (score 1):

A successful install of a package (such as `wget`) will contain references to the package in `setup.log`.

For example:

```
$ grep wget setup.log
2015/06/10 11:11:14 Downloaded F:\downloads\cygwin/ftp%3a%2f%2fftp.mirrorservice.org%2fsites%2fsourceware.org%2fpub%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/pwget/pwget-2013.0911+gitaf1c897-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/10 11:11:25 Downloaded F:\downloads\cygwin/ftp%3a%2f%2fftp.mirrorservice.org%2fsites%2fsourceware.org%2fpub%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/wget/wget-1.16.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/10 11:12:00 Extracting from file://F:\downloads\cygwin/ftp%3a%2f%2fftp.mirrorservice.org%2fsites%2fsourceware.org%2fpub%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/pwget/pwget-2013.0911+gitaf1c897-2.tar.bz2
2015/06/10 11:12:03 Extracting from file://F:\downloads\cygwin/ftp%3a%2f%2fftp.mirrorservice.org%2fsites%2fsourceware.org%2fpub%2fcygwin%2f/x86_64/release/wget/wget-1.16.3-1.tar.xz
2015/06/10 11:15:59 running: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe --norc --noprofile "/etc/postinstall/wget.sh"
```

---

Source [Cygwin Faq](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.setup.setup-fails)

> **2.15. What if setup fails?**     First, make sure that you are using the latest version of Cygwin Setup. The latest version is always
>   available from the Cygwin Home Page at https://cygwin.com/.
>
> If you are downloading from the Internet, setup will fail if it cannot
>   download the list of mirrors at https://cygwin.com/mirrors.html. It
>   could be that the network is too busy. Something similar could be the
>   cause of a download site not working. Try another mirror, or try again
>   later.
>
> If setup refuses to download a package that you know needs to be
>   upgraded, try deleting that package's entry from /etc/setup. If you
>   are reacting quickly to an announcement on the mailing list, it could
>   be that the mirror you are using doesn't have the latest copy yet. Try
>   another mirror, or try again tomorrow.
>
> **If setup has otherwise behaved strangely, check the files setup.log and setup.log.full in /var/log (C:\cygwin\var\log by default). It may
>   provide some clues as to what went wrong and why.**
>
> If you're still baffled, search the Cygwin mailing list for clues.
>   Others may have the same problem, and a solution may be posted there.
>   If that search proves fruitless, send a query to the Cygwin mailing
>   list. You must provide complete details in your query: version of
>   setup, options you selected, contents of setup.log and setup.log.full,
>   what happened that wasn't supposed to happen, etc.

Comment: Updated my question with information from the `setup.log`

Comment: @Soapy I have the same errors in `setup.log` but installations still succeed. It must be something else. Can you [edit] your question to include the complete log file?

Comment: Added the log file.

Comment: @Soapy There is no mention of `wget` in `setup.log`. I'm installing it myself to see what **should** be in there.

Comment: Yea I've tried it without command line switches, I'll try the latest version now...

Comment: Do you have `wget.lst.gz` in `/etc/setup`?